# Fazer login e ver se página está online com curl

Tags: php, javascript, libcurl

Eu desejo fazer login em diferentes páginas com `Curl` e ver se tudo está OK.
 Exemplo: login feito com sucesso me retorna um texto a tela "login ok" se não funcionou pega algum elemento da página de erro e me printa na tela em baixo do painel "login error" (usarei para testar proxys e criar chat bots mais pra frente). Como exemplo eu tentei fazer um código simples no Facebook, segue em baixo:

```
<?php

$login_email = 'meuemail@outook.com';
$login_pass = 'minhasenha';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://m.facebook.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'charset_test=€,´,€,´,水,Д,Є&email='.urlencode($login_email).'&pass='.urlencode($login_pass).'&login=Login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$fbMain = curl_exec($ch)
?>
```

O problema é que depois desse sistema simples de login não sei como fazer para imprimir em baixo o status que me diz se o login foi feito com sucesso ou não, exemplo do que quero fazer mais com Testador de proxy list:

```
192.173.0.1 Live
192.168.0.2 die
192.168.0.4 Live
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `curl_exec` retorna o HTML da requisição, e você também pode pegar o http code com a função `curl_getinfo`.

```
$document = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Com o retorno do HTML da para identificar determinadas strings que identifiquem se foi logado ou não. Eu geralmente uso um `strpos` nesses casos.

No seu caso, você pode dar um `echo $fbMain;` e ver o que retorna.